# Prevent a construction of instance with an invalid argument

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a constructor that receives an `ArrayList` of routes:

```
public Voo(ArrayList<Routes> routes, LocalDateTime dateTime, Duration duration) {
    if (routes.isEmpty()) {

    }

    this.routes = routes;
    this.dateTime = dateTime;
    this.duration = duration;
    this.status = Status.CONFIRMED;
}
```

How can I prevent the constructor from returning an instance of `Voo` if the `routes` received is empty?

Comment: `List.isEmpty()` seems like an OK way to check if a list be empty.  What is your question then?

Comment: You throw an exception, e.g. `throw new IllegalArgumentException("rotas may not be empty");`

Comment: Add in a null check on top of what @TimBiegeleisen mentioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically an `IllegalArgumentException` is thrown. e.g.

```
if (routes.isEmpty()) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("routes should be non-empty");
}
```

Comment: ty for the grammar fix,english isnt my main language. And it worked

Comment: No worries! Please up-vote my answer and mark as "answered" :)